# To Use the Observable Dictionary For Two Way Binding in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a sample app to check the two way binding for Observable Dictionary.When the Constructor is called then the Data is getting Binded correctly with the UI.But after that if I am trying to Update the ObservableDictionary then the Dictionary is getting updated but UI is not getting upddated.

This is my main page

```
public class TestPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableDictionary<int, string> DataDict = new ObservableDictionary<int, string>();
    public TestPage ()
    {

        this.BindingContext = DataDict;
        DataDict.Add(1, "One");
        DataDict.Add(2, "two");
        DataDict.Add(3, "Three");
        var editor = new Entry();
        editor.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

        editor.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty,string.Format("[1]"), BindingMode.TwoWay);

        var btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Check";
        btn.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;

        var vertical = new StackLayout();
        vertical.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        vertical.Children.Add(editor);
        vertical.Children.Add(btn);
        Content = vertical;
    }

    private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataDict[1] = DataDict[1] + DataDict[2];
    }
}
```

And this one is the ObservableDictionary I am trying to use

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count={Count}")]
public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
    INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Internal dictionary that holds values
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> underlyingDictionary;
    bool shouldRaiseNotifications = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event raised for collection change notification
    /// </summary>
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Event raise for property changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableDictionary()
        : this(new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>())
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that allows different storage initialization
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> store)
    {
        if (store == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("store");

        underlyingDictionary = store;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that takes an equality comparer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comparer">Comparison class</param>
    public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        : this(new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer))
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method turns off notifications until the returned object
    /// is Disposed. At that point, the entire dictionary is invalidated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IDisposable</returns>
    public IDisposable BeginMassUpdate()
    {
        return new MassUpdater(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an element with the provided key and value to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The object to use as the key of the element to add.
    /// </param><param name="value">The object to use as the value of the element to add.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="key"/> is null.
    /// </exception><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">An element with the same key already exists in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </exception><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/> is read-only.
    /// </exception>
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        var item = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
        underlyingDictionary.Add(item);
        OnNotifyAdd(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The object to add to the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.
    /// </exception>
    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        underlyingDictionary.Add(item);
        OnNotifyAdd(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all items from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only. 
    /// </exception>
    public void Clear()
    {
        underlyingDictionary.Clear();
        OnNotifyReset();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/> contains an element with the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/> contains an element with the key; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="key">The key to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="key"/> is null.
    /// </exception>
    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return underlyingDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the elements of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> to an <see cref="T:System.Array"/>, starting at a particular <see cref="T:System.Array"/> index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The one-dimensional <see cref="T:System.Array"/> that is the destination of the elements copied from <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>. The <see cref="T:System.Array"/> must have zero-based indexing.
    /// </param><param name="arrayIndex">The zero-based index in <paramref name="array"/> at which copying begins.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="array"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="arrayIndex"/> is less than 0.</exception>
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        underlyingDictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through the collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1"/> that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return underlyingDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the element with the specified key from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the element is successfully removed; otherwise, false.  This method also returns false if <paramref name="key"/> was not found in the original <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to remove.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="key"/> is null.
    /// </exception><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/> is read-only.
    /// </exception>
    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        TValue local = underlyingDictionary[key];
        bool flag = underlyingDictionary.Remove(key);
        OnNotifyRemove(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, local));

        return flag;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if <paramref name="item"/> was successfully removed from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if <paramref name="item"/> is not found in the original <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="item">The object to remove from the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.
    /// </exception>
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        bool flag = underlyingDictionary.Remove(item);
        if (flag)
            OnNotifyRemove(item);
        return flag;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> contains a specific value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if <paramref name="item"/> is found in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="item">The object to locate in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    ///                 </param>
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return underlyingDictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.IEnumerator"/> object that can be used to iterate through the collection.
    /// </returns>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return underlyingDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value associated with the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the object that implements <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/> contains an element with the specified key; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="key">The key whose value to get.
    /// </param><param name="value">When this method returns, the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the <paramref name="value"/> parameter. This parameter is passed uninitialized.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="key"/> is null.
    /// </exception>
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return underlyingDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The number of elements contained in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public int Count
    {
        get { return underlyingDictionary.Count; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> is read-only; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the element with the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The element with the specified key.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the element to get or set.
    /// </param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="key"/> is null.
    /// </exception><exception cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException">The property is retrieved and <paramref name="key"/> is not found.
    /// </exception><exception cref="T:System.NotSupportedException">The property is set and the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/> is read-only.
    /// </exception>
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return underlyingDictionary[key]; }
        set
        {
            if (underlyingDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var originalValue = underlyingDictionary[key];
                underlyingDictionary[key] = value;
                OnNotifyReplace(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value), new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, originalValue));
            }
            else
            {
                underlyingDictionary[key] = value;
                OnNotifyAdd(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> containing the keys of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> containing the keys of the object that implements <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return underlyingDictionary.Keys; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> containing the values in the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1"/> containing the values in the object that implements <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return underlyingDictionary.Values; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to notify insertions into the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item</param>
    protected void OnNotifyAdd(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(item.Key.ToString()));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to notify removals from the dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item</param>
    protected void OnNotifyRemove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(item.Key.ToString()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to notify replacements in the dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newItem">New item</param>
    /// <param name="oldItem">Old item</param>
    protected void OnNotifyReplace(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> newItem, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, newItem, oldItem));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(oldItem.Key.ToString()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is used to notify that the dictionary was completely reset.
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnNotifyReset()
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.CollectionChanged"/> event with the provided arguments.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Arguments of the event being raised.</param>
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (shouldRaiseNotifications == false)
            return;

        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the property change notification
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Property event args.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (shouldRaiseNotifications == false)
            return;

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    //IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// IDisposable class which turns off updating
    /// </summary>
    class MassUpdater : IDisposable
    {
        readonly ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> parent;

        public MassUpdater(ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            parent.shouldRaiseNotifications = false;
        }


        ~MassUpdater()
        {
            Debug.Assert(true, "Did not dispose returned object from ObservableDictionary.BeginMassUpdate!");
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            parent.shouldRaiseNotifications = true;
            parent.OnNotifyReset();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to update the UI when the Dictionary is getting updated.I have to use it as a two way data binding.

Comment: *"But after that if I am trying to Update the ObservableDictionary then the Dictionary is getting updated but UI is not getting upddated."* Could you specify the expected and actual behavior? Does the dictionary throw any event? What do you mean by *Dictionary is updated*? Updating the dictionary itself or its elements?

Comment: Can you show your ui code?

Comment: @dsdel main page is the ui code.Here I am Binding the entry with the Observable dictionary object.So when the page is getting loaded for the first time I am getting the value in the entry.On click of button i am updating the value of dictionary element and i want the Ui to be updated as well.

Comment: @Ankur, sorry.. if I understand your code correctly, you are firing the propertychanged for the key not for the value: OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(oldItem.Key.ToString())); The key is handled by add/remove - but the value property change is not handled - at least as far as I have seen : )

Comment: @dsdel thank u for u reply.So what should i add to make it working.

Comment: Try with: OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));